# How to unit test using a shim and a static factory method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, shim, factory-method

I have a class (with a protected constructor) that contains multiple static factory methods. I use these to make clear what parameters refer to. For example:

```
MyClass.FromFile(string filename);
MyClass.FromString(string filename);
MyClass.FromParameterSet(...);
```

I use these to give the different construction methods a name/meaning (I know there will be people telling me not to do this but please let's just discuss it this way, for the sake of the argument).

However, I am running into trouble when unit testing `MyClass`. I want to check if `MyClass` properly initializes its internal values because it does complex stuff. Of course it does not expose them. Usually a shim would solve the problem but with the static factory method I cannot create an instance in the very same way I will be in me "real code" because it will create an instance of `MyClass` and not `MyShimmedClass`.

The obvious answer is to not use static factory methods. I could do that but I am wondering if there is a way to *fix this*.

(I am using C# in case anyone is wondering.)

Comment: One option, though not ideal in some regards, is to use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute) on the assembly that contains MyClass to make the internal properties visible to your test assembly.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have understood your problem. Basically, it seems like you should have more the one UT(for each one of your static methods) and a few Integration tests to the instance which is implementing the class with the protected C'tor.

Comment: @OldFox I wanted to write unit tests (not integration tests) but the problem is that I cannot override the static method in the shim and thus will always return an instance of ```MyClass``` and not ```MyShimmedClass```.

Comment: @b0wter Well it seems that you are missing out the whole point of Unit testing.. However, why can't you fake a static method using MsFakes? Basically the competitive advantage of MsFakes on on Proxy based tools such as Moq is it allows you to fake static and sealed methods....

Comment: @OldFox Faking the static method is pointless because it is exactly the method I want to test. It creates an instance of a class and I need to check if it was initialized properly. Since the internals of the class are private I cannot peek into them. That is what made think about a shim. But the shim does not work since I cannot cast from ```MyClass``` to ```MyShimmedClass```.